# Load large data in select tag in Angular 4

Tags: html, angular

I have a select tag with thousands of options (names of cities), which the user can choose between as birth city, and is given by a service.
service file

```
getAllCities () {
return this.httpClient.get<City[]>(this.API_URL + 'cities');
}
```

In html component file:

```
<select
       class="form-control"
       id="city"
       name="city"
       ngModel
>
     <option disabled selected value=""> Select city</option>
     <option *ngFor="let elt of cities" [ngValue]="elt.code_city">
                {{ elt.city_name }}
     </option>
</select>
```

In component.ts file

```
getCities(){
this.shareService.getAllCities()
  .subscribe(
    (response: Array<City>) => {
      console.log(response);
      this.cities = response;
    },
    (error) => console.log('Error getting cities: ' + error)
  );
}
```

The problem is that my application block? and does not load the cities, have you any idea how I can do that in angular 4 (which method I must take to prevent this behavior) 
thanks

Comment: Are you able to see cities in console ?

Comment: You mean all cities in the world (380000) ? You maybe should consider a country filter before or a type ahead component.

Comment: If I were you I would change the input from select-list to an autocomplete one - in this way you won't have to load all the data up-front and block your UI.

Comment: Not all cities in the world, just 35000 city (France)

Comment: @TsvetanGanev: how i can do that? did you have an example please.

Comment: Do you know wich part is freezing your browser : javascript cities array acquirement or the DOM select rendering ?
You could test by only getting the cities array without displaying it and see if it still freezes.
For type ahead or autocomplete component you could see ng-bootstrap example here : https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples

Comment: @ibenjelloun: DOM select is the party which freezing my app, because, I can console.log the cities instantly : Array [ Object, Object, Object, 36360 more… ]  infos-personnelles.component.ts:43:13

Comment: What's the actual problem? I mean loading large data which freezes the DOM or is there any other issue?

Comment: As the DOM rendering is the issue, you could use the typeahead in a full front solution. Here is the ng-bootstrap stackblitz example : https://stackblitz.com/angular/ndaxykdpnag
You could copy past your cities array to the stackblitz for a performance check before implementing the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use `AutoComplete` input for such cases.

You can use one provided by NgPrime for Angular applications.

This is easy to use.

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

Limit your data binding to DOM. Binding too much data to single DOM may block your Application and your user may have to scroll too much to search his city. Use select with search([ng-select](https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select#/data-sources)) and use limitTo [pipe](http://embed.plnkr.co/LlViY10FWQW2xHfniw9k/) for limited data binding.